# What is killing my connection?

Tags: http, tcp

I have an API running on a server (Linux AWS), and from time I get in the client, the connection has been closed by the remote server.

Please, note that there is no message of errors/debug of what happened, so I am not sure how to tackle this.

Look at network packets.

Some facts:

- This happens on high load (CPU goes 100%+, RAM is fine).
- The bug is reproducible 100%, if I run the same requests in same order it will crash in the same request.
- Between the client and the server there is a load balancer (could it be this?).

The thing is I really wanted to find the reason (log/message/packet) of what is killing this connection, no idea how to do it, playing with tcpdump as we speak.

---

**EDIT**

The load balancer is droppign some messages about the payload being too big and has to write it in disk.

There are some wireshark traces (they do not match with the time that the connection is dropped) saying the TCP WINDOW is full.

Comment: Does the client use persistent http connection and a connection pool? If not for every request a new HTTP and TCP connection is opened and may persist for a time. If the number of open connection exceeds the capability of a middle ware system connections may get dropped. tcpdump would also be my starting point to investigate this issue, especially when connections are opened/closed (and how many of them are open).

Comment: At least the fact that *"The bug is reproducible 100%, if I run the same requests in same order it will crash in the same request"*  should make it easier to debug. - But to me that sounds as if the problem is in the API somewhere - increase logging verbosity in the API and if necessary the DEBUG level monitoring detail and go from there

Comment: @HBruijn I am at a trace level, (lowest) nothing shows up... The logs produce some tracking of the requests like: reciieved request #number, completed request#. I have managed to see some requests do not have a completed request log but nothing on the logs, adding some extra info on the main post.

Comment: @Robert thank you a lot, used tpcdump and analyzed some packages in wireshark, saw some TCP WINDOW FULL messages, not sure what it means will investigate